# OCaml zip elements of an array 2 by 2

Tags: ocaml

I need to check if an array is correctly sorted in OCaml.

Therefore, I was thinking to group the characters 2 by 2 and then do a fold operation where I compare them.

However, I don't know how to group them.

In Scala it would look something like this:

```
val k = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
k.zip(k.tail)
```

Any idea how that would look in OCaml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Array.init` function, to create a new array and fill it with the pairs, e.g..

```
let zip xs ys = Array.init (Array.length xs) (fun i -> x.(i),y.(i))
```

However, I wouldn't recommend this approach. There is no reason to create an intermediate data structures if you can easily express your algorithm easily with the recursive function.

And if you need to compare array `xs` with array `ys`, then you can just do `xs = ys`.

It also looks like, that you would like not to create a zip of two arrays, but extract pairs of consecutive elements from an array, here how it can be done with `Array.init`:

```
let zip_with_tail xs = match Array.length xs with
  | 0 | 1 -> [| |]
  | n -> Array.init (n-1) (fun i -> xs.(i),xs.(i+1))
```

Compare it with the `is_sorted` function, that doesn't use intermediate data structures:

> `let is_sorted xs =
>   let rec ordered i = i = 0 || xs.(i-1) <= xs.(i) && ordered (i-1) in
>   match Array.length xs with
>   | 0 | 1 -> true
>   | n -> ordered (n-1)`

The style decorate/process/undecorate works fine with lazy sequences, in compilers that are good in deforesting. For example in Haskell. Or in languages that are already so slow, that there is no need to bother. 
I'm not sure about Scala, whether their array is lazy or not. In any case, the OCaml array is a concrete data structure, and OCaml compiler will not optimize it (and shouldn't - semantics of an array will not allow to do this). However, this style of programming is still applicable in OCaml. You can user `Core` library, that provides a lazy container called `Sequence`. With which you can easily define `zip_with_tail` in the same way, as in Scala:

```
 let zip_with_tail xs = Sequence.(zip xs (drop xs 1))
```

Here is an example:

```
# let xs = Sequence.of_list [1;2;3;4;5;6];;
val xs : int Core_kernel.Std.Sequence.t = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
# zip_with_tail xs;;
- : (int * int) Core_kernel.Std.Sequence.t =
{(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)}
```

So, you can define the `is_sorted` nicely:

```
let is_sorted xs = zip_with_tail xs |>
                   Sequence.for_all ~f:(fun (x,y) -> x <= y)
```

Here `zip_with_tail xs` will not create an intermediate array, it actually has O(1) complexity. Underneath the hood it will return a function, that will generate elements. And `Sequence.for_all` will check that they are all sorted.

Comment: (I think there's just one array, and OP wants to compare each element to the next.)

Comment: I think you're right! Yeah, now scala code makes sense to me. Will update the post.

Answer (score 2):

This will make an array into a list of pairs of adjacent elements:

```
let a2pairs a =
    let mkpr x (prevo, prs) =
        match prevo with
        | None -> (Some x, [])
        | Some y -> (Some x, (x, y) :: prs)
    in
    snd (Array.fold_right mkpr a (None, []))
```

It works like this:

```
# a2pairs [| 1;2;3;4 |];;
- : (int * int) list = [(1, 2); (2, 3); (3, 4)]
```

But I agree with @ivg that creating this intermediate data structure is probably not worth it. You can use almost the same function to compare adjacent elements and accumulate a boolean that says whether they were all in the right order.